# Access primary color of prebuilt schemes

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I set up a new project using

`ng new app`

`ng add @angular/material`

I included the following line in `styles.css`:

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

I want to apply the primary color of the deeppurple-amber theme to a `<p>` element.

How can I extract the primary color of a prebuilt scheme and apply it to my own component in Angular 6??

Comment: The documentation for that guide should work for all versions of Angular. What didn't work on your side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of importing the pre-built theme, include the [content of the pre-built theme](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6.0.x/src/lib/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss) instead.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

// Include non-theme styles for core.
@include mat-core();

// Define a theme.
$primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent);

// Include all theme styles for the components.
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

You can then access the palettes and colors and [theme your own components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components).

Comment: In this case, the size of the output bundle is too large due to the inclusion of styles. How to deal with this?

Comment: Too large relative to what? You are probably doing something wrong or duplicating/including something you don't need. This shouldn't be any different in size than a pre-built theme as it is the identical code. Start a new question if you need debugging help.

Comment: Any idea whats wrong if it does not recognize $primary even if 1 1:1 copy the last file of the link you posted?

Comment: Those are code snippets/examples, not full working code. In the last block, it is assumed that `$primary` is defined based on the example in the code block before it.